# Help with an improper integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Can someone please help me evaluate this improper integral?

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\{-au^{-a}-u\}du$$ for $a>0.$

Comment: A general expression for the integral $I$ as a function of the parameter $a$ may be extremely difficult to find. The much easier problem evaluating the integral for special cases like $a=1$ or $a=$ complicated enough already.